# never uninstall my application?

Tags: android

can i set any setting for can't uninstall my application by user?is it possible in android code?

Thanks All

Comment: I certainly hope it's not possible.

Comment: You know that has as soon as someone knows that your application is like that they will never install it right?

Comment: @I know,but some application very need to safe our mobile,How is possible?

Comment: NO! You do NOT need to have an app be uninstallable in order to keep it safe! -.-

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop uninstallation of application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477206/stop-uninstallation-of-application)

Comment: Create your own OS and you will have happiness!

Answer (score 5):

No, that is not possible, never was possible, never will be possible. And thank God for that.

Comment: It is definitely possible, if the app is pre-installed in firmware. That's not very common, of course, and probably does not fit what the OP was inquiring about. However, for anyone who visits this question later, I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: Yes, I was just assuming that TS meant an installable app.

Comment: @CommonsWare, you actually can uninstall those apps too. You just need to root the device and remove the application from system/apps folder.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously wanna make a trojan/virius for android.

And the answer is no unless you making a custom firmware.