# Monitor my own application uninstalled

Tags: android

I want to notice my app be uninstalled so that i could start a web browser to collect the information why user uninstall it.
I try to make a broadcast receiver to listen to the event that app uninstall,but it doesn't work.Because the receiver only receiver the broadcast other app uninstall.

Comment: You cannot get control when your application is uninstalled -- sorry!

Comment: As a user, I would find that really annoying. And there are possible security implications.

Comment: i know it's annoying,but your use experience will also help us to improve our product.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way by which the app itself gets any event when it is getting uninstalled.
here is similar answer. [Stop uninstallation of application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4477510/519718)

Comment: sorry it is not what i need,but also thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible, seriously. If you have two apps installed on device, you can make your second app to watch a list of installed apps by timer, but it's obviously not a good idea. If you have only one app on device, you can do just nothing.